# Programmatically retrying a failed work item update

Tags: c#, tfs, tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem

I have a TFS `ISubscriber` implementation that modifies work items on `WorkItemChangedEvent`s. Occasionally we get an `ItemAlreadyUpdatedOnServerException` due to contention with TFS Build associating the work item with a build.

Whilst the event handler updates several work item fields, the conflict only occurs on updating the history field. We are using `WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll)` to save the work item.

I would like to attempt to retry the work item update in this specific scenario. Having spent quite a bit of time thinking about this and looking at what is possible in the API, the best I can come up with is to:

1. Call `WorkItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll)`
2. Catch the `ItemAlreadyUpdatedOnServerException` and then in the catch block
3. Query and store all `Fields` that are `IsDirty` and not `IsComputed` on the work item that failed to save
4. Resync the work item to the latest revision using `WorkItem.SyncToLatest()`
5. Reapply the `Field` values that were identified as dirty in step 3.
6. Attempt the save again

I'm reasonably confident this is workable, but I was wondering if there is anything I have missed or if there is a better solution native to the TFS API?

(Sorry no code, I can update and provide a sample once I'm at a desktop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with the implementation I outlined in the original question and it appears to work well. Here is a sample implementation of the retry logic, which is called from the catch block of an `ItemAlreadyUpdatedOnServerException` exception:

```
private void RetryWorkItemSave(WorkItem workItem)
{
        //Get the non-computed dirty fields from the failed update
        var dirtyFields = workItem.Fields.Cast<Field>()
                  .Where(w => w.IsDirty && !w.IsComputed)
                  .ToDictionary((f) => f.ReferenceName, (f) => f.Value); 

        //Sync the work item to the latest version
        workItem.SyncToLatest();

        //Reapply the original field changes
        foreach (var field in dirtyFields)
        {
            if (workItem.Fields[field.Key].IsEditable)
            {
                workItem[field.Key] = field.Value;
            }
        }

        workItem.Save(SaveFlags.MergeAll);
}
```